# How to show full content in drop down column selection box

Tags: r, shiny, dt

when use DT to show a data frame in shiny app. it can't show full content in drop down column selection box, just as the below picture, the last word is truncated in the drop-down selection box.

Picture for truncated display:

[image]

```
output$table_cm<-renderDataTable(cm_display(),filter = 'top',selection ="none",extensions = 'Buttons',rownames =F,escape = FALSE,
                               options = list(pageLength = nrow(cm_display()),scrollX = TRUE,scrollY = nrow(cm_display())+600,autoWidth = TRUE,
                                              dom = 'Bfrtip',buttons = c('excel')))
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)